# How to set borders and other styles of a plugin object from JSAPI side?

Tags: c++, html, firebreath

I have this::

```
FB::DOM::ElementPtr _element=m_host->getDOMWindow()->getDocument()->getBody()->getElementById("plugin0");
```

I got the element(i.e. object tag of the plugin that i wanted) by ID. It's compiling. I now want to SET its property from the JSAPI side...like border color style and width....
 I went through [this page](http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/class%20FB%20DOM%20Element) . I could find only 1 method "setInnerHtml"...which sets something. What should i pass in its argument...?it has std::string type...so that I can manipulate the plugin's document. Any ideas...
**Basically I want to set the attribute of a tag from PluginAPI side.....**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly? You'd be much better off putting the plugin in a div at 100%x100% and then managing the border of the div.  For something like this I'd probably just use:

```
m_host->evaluateJavascript("document.getElementById('pluginCont').style.border = '1px solid black';");
```

That'll be the easiest.  You could also look at the DOM abstraction code and add some tools for managing CSS; note that on IE you may need to use special activex methods to do this, which is why I dont' recommend just doing it through `getDOMElement()` (which is a shorthand, btw, for the long code you have in your example)

Comment: Appreciate your reply. I was mostly interested in painting the border on the plugin mainly through c++. Agreed I can opt this method, but i want to do this way

Comment: @taxilian...I was hoping I could paint the plugin window with a border using Windows GDI. I came to know about the WinMessageWindow.h thing which can generate messages for window to paint borders and other things on the client rectangle. How should I use it in Windows Attached Event.

Comment: No reason you couldn't, but I have no idea what that has to do with this question.  If your question is about how to draw, I'd go look at the FBTestPlugin example and/or search for how to draw with firebreath; if you can't find it, write a question about that.

Comment: ... I love the way that I answered your question, but you unaccepted my answer because you had a different (as far as I can tell unrelated) question that I hadn't answered? That is not a particularly good way to build goodwill on stackoverflow.

Comment: @taxilian..will remember that

Comment: thanks =] I don't mind you looking for a clear answer, but it's frustrating to have nothing picked as an answer and nothing indicating why an answer I typed isn't selected =]